# Best practices for creation of Akka microkernel init script

Tags: scala, akka, init

I'm currently writing an application with Scala 2.10.2, Akka 2.2.1, Sbt 0.13 and the akka-sbt-plugin. I can run the 'dist' command, which creates a 'start' script to run the microkernel, but it isn't a proper init script supporting 'start', 'stop', 'status' and so on.

I'd eventually like to deploy it on CentOS 6.3 or 6.4, so I need a proper initscript at some point. I could write one myself, but I think that it would be better if there was some sort of standardized script that everyone uses (I can't be the only one having this problem). Is there a best practice that has been adopted by the Akka community?

Thanks.

Comment: The main reason that such script is not provided is that simply there would be too many platforms to support. This is a good candidate for community contribution, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've searched quite a bit and my conclusion is **no** there is not a documented best practice for this. The closest I found to directly address this is https://github.com/bwmcadams/sbt-akka-bivy which can generate an upstart script.